# c# - Select specific text boxes on WebBrowser and write in them

Tags: c#

how would I select a specific text box on a web browser (the default c# webbrowser) and write a string in it? I have been thinking of webrequests but that may be illegal due to the amount of packets you will send to the host server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just wanting to fill in a field, you need to use the DOM. Here are some examples that assume your browser is named `browser` and has navigated to google.com.

### WPF

```
     mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 htmlDoc = browser.Document as mshtml.IHTMLDocument2;
     ((mshtml.HTMLInputElement)htmlDoc.all.item("lst-ib")).value = "wpf web browser access dom";
```

### WinForms

```
     HtmlDocument htmlDoc = browser.Document;
     htmlDoc.All["lst-ib"].InnerText = "c# web browser access dom";
```

Comment: Note that I said "some examples". There are other ways to do it, but that should get you started. You can use the Object Browser to learn more about the various objects, as well as search around on how to work with the DOM.